# Word 2007 Addin Ribbon - InternalStartup

Tags: c#, ms-word, ribbon, word-addins

With Visual Studio 2013 I target the .NET Framework 4, and created a single add-in that targets both Office 2007 and Office 2010. I choose a 2010 Addin but it should work in 2007 accordind to this link:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2010/06/04/creating-an-add-in-for-office-2007-and-office-2010-that-lights-up-on-office-2010-mclean-schofield/

I used the ribbon designer (not the ribbon xml) In my AddInin the startup method I have the following:

```
private void InternalStartup()
{
  this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
  this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
}

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  ((Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)this.Application).NewDocument += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_NewDocumentEventHandler(Application_NewDocument);
  this.Application.DocumentBeforeClose += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeCloseEventHandler(Application_DocumentBeforeClose);

//THIS LINE FAILS IN Word 2007 but not in Word 2010
this.Application.ActiveDocument.Saved = false;
}
```

Basically I'm capturing the close event and I do some custom code of my own in that event. This works perfectly in 2010. In 2007 the ribbon installs and some functionality works however when I close the document my 'Application_DocumentBeforeClose' close event dosnt get called in Word 2007. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I changed my code as suggested however the line below fails in Word 2007 when I open a document with error - 'This command is not available because no document is open.'

```
this.Application.ActiveDocument.Saved = false;
```

Comment: Changes were made in the 2010 Ribbon that 2007 does not support. Did you create your Ribbon using the VSTO Ribbon Designer or do you use Ribbon XML? If Ribbon XML, which namespace did you use?

Comment: Cindy I used the ribbon designer not the xml. My code exists in the WordAdd class.

Comment: You shouldn't put code in InternalStartup, that's for VSTO's code. Put the DocumentBeforeClose initialization in ThisAddIn_Startup. Sorry I didn't see that before, but since your Title emphasizes the Ribbon, that's what I was concentrating on. You might want to edit that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the similar forum thread - [Word DocumentBeforeClose not firing](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43dece2f-5d09-486c-b501-13f4ebdcec4a/word-documentbeforeclose-not-firing?forum=vsto). Here is what it states:

> If we open a document, Word will detect whether the new document is modifed. If it is the blank document from scratch, Word uses it to host the target document directly. So in this case, it is not considered a Close action. Hence, the DocumentBeforeClose does not fire.

Comment: I tried that but the when I run it in Word 2007 it throws an error at: this.Application.ActiveDocument.Saved = false; -  'This command is not available because no document is open.'

Comment: What value does it return?